# compare quoted strings in python

Tags: python

I have a file that has several lines with different values for FILE_TYPE as below

```
CHEK_TP="SHA-1" FILE_TYPE="CONFIG_PARAMS" FILE_NAME="Config.cfg" CHEK_VL="358315596CBFA463534299BF3AC5E5E89410190F"
CHEK_TP="SHA-1" FILE_TYPE="APPL_ONE_PARAMS" FILE_NAME="Application_one.hex" CHEK_VL="358315596CBFA463534299BF3AC5E5E89410190F"
```

I am using `readline` function to read the lines from file and want to compare that line has `FILE_TYPE="APPL_ONE_PARAMS"` in it and print it.

I am using below statement to compare, but it does not work.

`if "FILE_TYPE=\"APPL_ONE_PARAMS\"" in line:`

How to check a line has certain string (if is is in double quotes).

Comment: Instead of using escape characters you can use single quotes around your string and then you can use the double quotes inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'FILE_TYPE="APPL_ONE_PARAMS"' in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: what did you test it against? plus, what was your result?

Comment: It was mistake on my side, this works thanks

Answer (score 1):

File :

```
CHEK_TP="SHA-1" FILE_TYPE="CONFIG_PARAMS" FILE_NAME="Config.cfg" CHEK_VL="358315596CBFA463534299BF3AC5E5E89410190F"
CHEK_TP="SHA-1" FILE_TYPE="APPL_ONE_PARAMS" FILE_NAME="Application_one.hex" CHEK_VL="358315596CBFA463534299BF3AC5E5E89410190F"
```

Code :

```
file = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
val = 'FILE_TYPE="APPL_ONE_PARAMS"'
for line in lines:
  if val in line:
    print(val)
```

Output :

```
FILE_TYPE="APPL_ONE_PARAMS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying wrapping your string in single quotes instead.

Ex:

```
if 'FILE_TYPE == \"APPL_ONE_PARAMS\"' in line:
```